# How to use node-http-proxy for HTTP to HTTPS routing?

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, node-http-proxy

Here's the module version that I'm using:

```
$ npm list -g | grep proxy
├─┬ http-proxy@0.10.0
```

A webservice calls into my machine and my task is to proxy the request to a different url and host with an additional query parameter based on the contents of the request's body:

```
var http      = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
    form2json = require('form2json');

httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
  // my custom logic
  var fullBody = '';
  req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      // append the current chunk of data to the fullBody variable
      fullBody += chunk.toString();
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
      var jsonBody = form2json.decode(fullBody);
      var payload = JSON.parse(jsonBody.payload);
      req.url = '/my_couch_db/_design/ddoc_name/_update/my_handler?id="' + payload.id + '"';

      // standard proxy stuff
      proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
        changeOrigin: true,
        host: 'my.cloudant.com',
        port: 443,
        https: true
      });
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

But I keep running into errors like: `An error has occurred: {"code":"ECONNRESET"}`

Anyone have an idea about what needs to be fixed here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This did the trick for me:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var options = {
  changeOrigin: true,
  target: {
      https: true
  }
}

httpProxy.createServer(443, 'www.google.com', options).listen(8001);
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron, that is the first useful answer I've received on this topic in a long time and one that actually works!

Answer (score 5):

To forward all requests that come in on port `3000` to `https://google.com`:

```
const https = require('https')
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy')

httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: 'https://google.com',
  agent: https.globalAgent,
  headers: {
    host: 'google.com'
  }
}).listen(3000)
```

Example inspired by https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/examples/http/proxy-http-to-https.js.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error, this worked for me:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var https = require('https');

var KEY  = 'newfile.key.pem';
var CERT = 'newfile.crt.pem';

httpProxy.createServer({
  changeOrigin: true,
  target: 'https://example.com',
  agent: new https.Agent({
    port: 443,
    key: fs.readFileSync(KEY),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(CERT)
  })
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `http-proxy@1.18.1`, I turn off the `secure`, and it works.

```js
const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ hostRewrite: true });
apiProxy.web(req, res, {
   target: "https://example.com",
   secure: false,
   changeOrigin: true,
});
```